# Cannot synchronize contacts on Huawei Honor 8

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, google-account, huawei, google-contacts

I just acquired the new Huawei Honor 8 from China (international version), but I have a few issues with the contacts. When I synchronize the contacts from my Microsoft account, I only retrieve 16 contacts in my list (whereas I have 300+ contacts). I checked the parameters, they are not hidden, it just managed to synchronize only 16 contacts.

I decided to migrate my Microsoft account contacts to my Google account, so I can try to synchronize the Google contacts on my phone. Once I managed to do it on the Google website from my computer, I found a bad surprise in the contact app : there is no option to synchronize Google contacts. HiCloud, Outlook, Facebook messenger, Linkedin, Skype and WeChat are the only options here. Have I missed something ? Do I need an extra app to do this ?

I'm wondering if this issue could be related to the Chinese ROM shipped on my phone, would you recommend to install a new ROM ?

**Edit** : I have installed "Google sync contacts" by directly downloading the APK. Now i can see the Google account in the list of the synchronized accounts in the contact app. But, after having double checked that the synchronization is activated for this account and a reboot, still 0 contact from Google in the list.

Comment: On your device there is any Google relevant application? My guess is you have to install on your phone Google services like Google Play, Framework and so.

Comment: I have the Play Store, Youtube and Gmail so I think the Google services & framework are OK. I have also installed an extra apk, see my edit

Comment: Then check your Google account sync settings in `Settings` -> `Accounts` -> `Google`, make sure `Contacts` are selected.

Comment: It is selected, this was what I meant by saying "having double checked that the synchronization is activated"

Comment: I'm also on Chinese version (FRD-AL00).
I have exactly the same problem with contacts. Did you manage to have it working?
Alex

Comment: Yes, strangely you have to initiate the synchronization from the Outlook app.  Go to Parameters > select your account > toggle the contacts synchronization.

Comment: Hi, looks like you've found the solution by yourself, which is great! Consider posting it as a proper answer since [self-answering is not only allowed but even encouraged](//android.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer). Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You have to go on the app list look for `Google sync contacts`trust the app and give the app access to contacts, after a restart you will have access to your google contacts.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with my Honor Note 8 Chinese version (EDI-AL10). I tried a few things, including installing Google Contacts Sync, Services, and Framework. Nothing fixed the issue until I noticed that Google Contacts Sync didn't have system permission to access contacts, once I enabled that and restarted all my contacts showed up.

Answer (score 0):

Struggled for ages with this (Huawei P9) - in the end it was donlaoding and installing the right version of google contacts sync apk that worked;
http://www.apkmirror.com/apk/google-inc/google-contacts-sync/google-contacts-sync-6-0-1-release/google-contacts-sync-6-0-1-android-apk-download/